# How do I make a TwoLineListItem?

Tags: android

I want to make a setings menu like this:
[image]

Is there a definitive guide on how to make `TwoLineListItem`'s anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, extend PreferenceActivity and in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);      
    getPreferences();
}
```

Where you can inflate your view using a preferences.xml file - add a folder called xml to your res folder and add an xml file with stuff like:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
       android:title="@string/pref_sub_notify"
       android:defaultValue="true"
       android:summary="@string/pref_sub_notify_summary"
       android:key="subNotifyPref" />

  <ListPreference
       android:title="@string/pref_sub_expiry_warn"
       android:summary="@string/pref_sub_expiry_summary"           
       android:key="subExpiryDelayPref"
       android:defaultValue="7"
       android:entries="@array/sub_expiry_delay"
       android:entryValues="@array/sub_expiry_delay_values" />
```

In this case, the title is your first line and the summary is the second line.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a custom listrow with a custom adapter.

Here is an example:
http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom `View` and a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) may help. If you are working on a Settings Activity, why not extend [PreferenceActivity](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good [tutorial here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) on how to create custom list items.  The basic idea is that you define the layout of the list item just as you define the layout for an `Activity`.  You then subclass `ArrayAdapter` (or `BaseAdapter`), and override the `getView(...)` method to return your custom list item `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my desired list's item should have an image followed by two strings, one above the other (just as you want). I found the solution [here](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-listview-with-two-textview-and-imageview/). It worked easily for me and I think it will work well for you too (you just need to remove the `ImageView` part appropriately).